# Chrome Options JQuery Plug-in

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, user-interface

Is there a jquery plug-in that that works like the Chrome Options UI?

As you can see, you can jump in between levels. When you click on an option that has sub-options a new tab slides open.

Otherwise, any good resources / articles on replicating this functionality?

[image: Chrome Tabs]

Answer (score 1):

Its all magic with CSS and javascript.

You need to create dialogs that stick to the side and fade in/out based on user action.

---

Start up example: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/gqxWv/6/

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at https://github.com/frankkohlhepp/fancy-settings, which is for Chrome extensions, but you might be able to make it work outside of that scope.